# php-fpm cannot set error_reporting

Tags: php

I have PHP 7.4.12 with php-fpm + nginx and when I put this into /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
php_admin_flag[error_reporting] = E_ALL
```

or

```
php_admin_flag[error_reporting] = 32767
```

I cannot start php-fpm. The error is:

```
php-fpm[31447]: [20-Nov-2020 10:39:00] ERROR: [/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:430] error while parsing 'php_admin_flag[error_reporting]' : invalid boolean value
php-fpm[31447]: [20-Nov-2020 10:39:00] ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf from /etc/php-fpm.conf at line 430
php-fpm[31447]: [20-Nov-2020 10:39:00] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php-fpm.conf'
php-fpm[31447]: [20-Nov-2020 10:39:00] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `php_admin_value` not `php_admin_flag`